# bedeutet diese Präposition *über* mittels in diesem Zusammenhang?

Tags: meaning-in-context, context

> Schließlich führt die Niedrigzinspolitik der EZB bei den Privatleuten zu einer schleichenden Enteignung der Spargelder und der privaten Altersvorsorge durch negative Realzinsen und kann eine Blasenbildung bei »Ersatzwertspeichern« wie Immobilien und Aktien nach sich ziehen. Das kann letztlich **über** die Preis-/Lohnspirale in eine Inflation münden, wenn die Banken beginnen, das viele günstige Geld durch Kreditvergabe in den Wirtschaftskreislauf zu pumpen.

bedeutet diese Präposition *über*  mittels in diesem Zusammenhang ?

Comment: Was sagt denn das Wörterbuch zu "über"? Welche Alternativen lassen Dich zweifeln?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, *über* means *via*. It cannot be replaced by *mittels*, which would translate to *by means of* or *by use of*.